# Scrapy parses a certain portion of a site and ignores the rest

Tags: python, scrapy

When I run my scraper it scrapes around 200 records from a site whereas the very site contains around 250 records. I can't figure out any mistakes I've made while creating it. Any help would be vastly appreciated.

### "items.py" includes:

```
import scrapy
class WiseowlItem(scrapy.Item):
    Name = scrapy.Field()
    Url= scrapy.Field()
```

### crawlspider named "wiseowlsp.py" includes:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class WiseowlspSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "wiseowlsp"
    allowed_domains = ['www.wiseowl.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="woMenuItem"]')),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="woPaging tac"]'),
            callback='parse_items')]

    def parse_items(self, response):
        page = response.xpath('//div[@class="woVideoListRow"]')
        for title in page:
            AA = title.xpath('.//p[@class="woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle"]/a/text()').extract()
            BB = title.xpath('.//p[@class="woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle"]/a/@href').extract()
            yield {'Name':AA,'Url':BB}
```

In case I use the style I'm gonna paste I get the result I want, but I expected to avoid using Regex.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from wiseowl.items import WiseowlItem

class WiseowlspSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "wiseowlsp"
    allowed_domains = ["wiseowl.co.uk"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('uk/videos/.*')),callback='parse_items', follow=True)]

    def parse_items(self, response):
        page = response.xpath('//div[@class="woVideoListRow"]')
        for title in page:
            item=WiseowlItem()
            item["Name"] = title.xpath('.//p[@class="woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle"]/a/text()').extract()
            item["Url"] = title.xpath('.//p[@class="woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle"]/a/@href').extract()
            yield item
```

In this case restrict_xpaths always omit the first page and start scraping from the next page until it ends.I believe there should be any way or method (limiting in this restrict_xpaths pattern) applying which data of first page can also be scraped. Expecting someone to give a little push.

Answer (score 2):

I hate using typical `Rule` and `LinkExtractor`, its difficult to understand, Scrapy does everything by itself.

I always prefer using `start_requests` method which is the entry point of your Spider

For the website you are scraping, I would first develop logic in my mind, and then translate the into code.

1. Go to home page
2. Go to each category page on left
3. On each page scrape each Item
4. On each page go to next page if there is Next Page link

This is 100% working code.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.http.request import Request
import logging

class WiseowlspSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "wiseowlsp"

    def start_requests(self):
        # got to home page
        yield Request(url = "http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/", callback = self.parse_home_page)


    def parse_home_page(self, response):
        # parse all links on left
        for cat in response.css(".woMenuList > li"):
            logging.info("\n\n\nScraping Category: %s" % (cat.css("a::text").extract_first()))
        yield Request(url = "http://www.wiseowl.co.uk" + cat.css("a::attr(href)").extract_first() , callback = self.parse_listing_page)


    def parse_listing_page(self, response):
        items = response.xpath('//div[@class="woVideoListRow"]')
        for title in items:
            AA = title.xpath('.//p[@class="woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle"]/a/text()').extract()
            BB = title.xpath('.//p[@class="woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle"]/a/@href').extract()
            yield {'Name':AA,'Url':BB}


        next_page = response.css("a.woPagingNext::attr(href)").extract_first()

        if next_page is not None:
        logging.info("\n\n\nGoing to next page %s" % (next_page))
        # If there is next page scrape it
        yield Request(url = "http://www.wiseowl.co.uk" + next_page , callback = self.parse_listing_page)
    else:
        for more_pages in response.css("a.woPagingItem"):
                next_page = more_pages.css("::attr(href)").extract_first()

            logging.info("\n\n\nGoing to next page %s" % (next_page))
            # If there is next page scrape it
            yield Request(url = "http://www.wiseowl.co.uk" + next_page , callback = self.parse_listing_page)
```

and in `settings.py` write this

```
# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Override the default request headers:
DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'
}
```

Now you can see my code can be easily read from top-to-bottom and you can understand its logic.

Comment: "I hate using typical Rule and LinkExtractor, its difficult to understand" well said, beginners should be down right not allowed to use CrawlSpider. After all Explicit is better than Implicit.

Comment: yeah when using `Rule and LinkExtractor`  scrapy does most of things by itself ... while my proposed solution is what beginners should follow ... you can just read my code top-to-bottom and can understand what it does ... even I have been doing Data Scraping for 3 years and never used Rule and LinkExtractor

Comment: Thanks sir Umair, for your kind and sweet effort. It does run smoothly but fetches only 60 records. The only thing i did to your code before running is [from scrapy.http.request import Request]. If anything i should add or remove at this point, I expect you will let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: @SMth80 See my edits ... its 100% working code ... I scraped 579 items

Comment: Dear sir Umair, perhaps it's my incapability that I can't make your code work. Anyways, thanks again. By the way, the site contains 246 items in total.